# Conseguir valor del tag dentro de un tr dinámico al pulsar un botón o enlace en jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tengo un listado de clientes con varias filas, en cada fila almaceno el id del cliente en el tr de cada una de ellas.
Quiero conseguir el valor del atributo `id` que esta en la columna tr.

Lo he conseguido de una forma y es con el atributo data de html5, pero si intento conseguirlo, como siempre lo he hecho que es el con metodo val de jquery, no lo consigo,
Os pongo un ejemplo sencillo de lo que quiero

```
<div class="table-responsive">   
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr id="primerafila">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td><a href="" id="superenlace">boton6</a></td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
          </tr>
           <tr data-identificador="segundafila">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td id="bot4sec2"><button id="superbotton">4</button></td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>   </table> </div>


<script type="text/javascript">   
    $('document').ready(function(){
         var segundaColumna = $("#superbotton").parents('tr');   
         console.log(segundaColumna.data('identificador'));

         var primeraColumna = $("#superenlace").parents('tr');   
         console.log(primeraColumna.val('#id')); 
</script>
```

Lo que tendría que salir en la primera fila es "primerafila" pulsando el enlace y en la segunda fila tendría que conseguir "segundafila" pulsando el botón

Me gustaría saber mas alternativas para conseguir un valor de un tr cuando el valor del tr es dinámico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método `.attr()` de jQuery para obtener cualquier atributo, así con `.attr('id')` podrás obtener el valor del id. (Más información: http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

A su vez, con el método `.click()` o con el `.on()` pasando como primer argumento 'click', podrás asignar un manejador de eventos tras un clic sobre algún elemento. (Más información: http://api.jquery.com/click/ - http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Veo también algunos problemas de sintaxis en tu código, y falta cerrar llaves y paréntesis en el script.

**HTML**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="primerafila">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td><a href="#" id="superenlace">boton6</a></td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="segundafila">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td id="bot4sec2">
          <button id="superbotton">4</button>
        </td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#superenlace').on('click', function() {
    var primeraColumna = $("#superenlace").parents('tr');
    console.log(primeraColumna.attr('id'));
  });
  $('#superbotton').on('click', function() {
    var segundaColumna = $("#superbotton").parents('tr');
    console.log(segundaColumna.attr('id'));
  });
});
```

Tu ejemplo funcionando
https://jsfiddle.net/2zau8jpn/

Comment: Bueno, los problemas de sintaxis probablemente se deban a que habia algunos codigos comentados y los he ido borrando, igual he borrado de mas. De todas formas te agredezco tu respuesta, muy documentada y extensa.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con el **.attr()** de jquery.

```
$(tr).attr("id");
```

Comment: Gracias, funciona.

Answer (score -1):

Lo Podrías resolver con una función que capture el valor en el onclick del button o link. al momento de crear la tabla y asignarle el value a los tr, le asignas la función capturavalor(value) al onclick

```js
    $('document').ready(function(){
         var segundaColumna = $("#superbotton").parents('tr');   
         console.log(segundaColumna.data('identificador'));

         var primeraColumna = $("#superenlace").parents('tr');   
         console.log(primeraColumna.val('#id'));
    }); 
function capturaValor(parametro){
alert(parametro);


}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">   
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr id="primerafila">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td><a href="" id="superenlace" onclick="capturaValor(6)">boton6</a></td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
          </tr>
           <tr data-identificador="segundafila">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td id="bot4sec2"><button id="superbotton" onclick="capturaValor(4)">4</button></td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>   </table> </div>
```

Comment: Igual, me he expresado mal, no quiero que me consiga el valor de la fila al pulsar el boton, quiero que al pulsar el boton, me consiga el valor de la etiqueta ID que hay en el tr, no obstante ya esta resuelto, era sustituir el val() por el attr().
Gracias